# unable to dequeue a cell with identifier TodoItemRow - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Tags: ios, objective-c

Getting the following error.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier TodoItemRow - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I kind of understand why this is happening but kind of not. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   self.items = @[@{@"name" : @"Take out the trash", @"category" : @"Home"}].mutableCopy;

   self.navigationItem.title = @"What needs to be done";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellItentifier = @"TodoItemRow";
    UITableViewCell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellItentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *item = self.items[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = item[@"name"];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a **Identifier** here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you use xib or storyboard? If you use it then, you may set you identifier as "TodoItemRow" and add `[self.tableView registerNib:<#(nullable UINib *)#> forCellReuseIdentifier:<#(nonnull NSString *)#>]`
 to your VC.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had a case issue. My cell identifier was totoitemrow but I had typed it as TodoItemRow in my code.